# Chazal empty barrels make the most noise

Tags: sources-mekorot, chazal

As far as i know there is a mamer chazal for empty barrels make the most noise. can any one help me find it

Answer (score 8):

The Gemara in Bava Metzia ([85b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=85b&format=text)) says

> אמר רב חמא מאי דכתיב בלב נבון תנוח חכמה ובקרב כסילים תודע בלב נבון תנוח חכמה זה ת"ח בן ת"ח ובקרב כסילים תודע זה ת"ח בן ע"ה אמר עולא היינו דאמרי אינשי אסתירא בלגינא קיש קיש קריא

The Gemara is using it as a parable of a Torah scholar who is from a family of ignoramuses, since he's the only Torah scholar in the family, he'll make a lot of noise around himself, just as a coin in an empty box

Comment: My rav brought this up in his shabbos drasha a few weeks ago! I mentioned that "the coin in an empty box making the most noise" was a particularly poignant lesson regarding politics...